# Adding a Helper SQL Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following View which seems to work quickly enough but when I look at the Execution Plan, it shows the Top N Sort in the second query taking ~90% due to it being repeated for every row in the first query.

Should I be adding an Index to the Loan table to help the ORDER BY clause?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ResourceItemStatus] AS
SELECT
    i.ID AS ItemID,
    i.ResourceID,
    i.DateAdded,
    i.LocationID,
    i.OwnerID,
    i.Barcode,
    i.MissingReasonID,
    i.DateRemoved,
    ll.PatronID,
    ll.ID AS LoanID,
    ll.IssueDateTime,
    ll.DueDate,
    ll.ReturnDateTime,
    ll.LoanTypeID,
    ll.RenewalCount,
    ll.DeleteSummary,
    ll.ReturnStatusID,
    ll.FineID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Loan WHERE Loan.ItemID = i.ID) AS LoanCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item WHERE Item.DateRemoved IS NULL AND Item.ResourceID = i.ResourceID) AS AvailableItemCount
FROM Item i
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        l.ID,
        l.ItemID,
        l.PatronID,
        l.IssueDateTime,
        l.DueDate,
        l.ReturnDateTime,
        l.LoanTypeID,
        l.RenewalCount,
        l.DeleteSummary,
        l.ReturnStatusID,
        l.FineID
    FROM Loan l
    WHERE l.ItemID = i.ID
    ORDER BY l.IssueDateTime DESC, l.ID DESC

) AS ll
```

Comment: I think this index may help: ItemID ASC, IssueDateTime DESC, l.ID DESC.

Comment: Do you need to be doing those inline selects? As written now those queries will run for every row returned. So if your query returns say 100 rows those will run 100 times. Same if it returns 100000000 rows.

Comment: Zane: I guess not but I thought COUNT(*) was very quick and is about as far as my SQL skills go!

Comment: Dan: I just tried that and it certainly changed the Execution Plan! Sort gone and replaced with your Index Seek and a Key Lookup. 
The question now is whether I keep the Index and use space or use the Windowed Aggregates Answer (which I am struggling to understand)

Comment: Dan: Turns out I already an index on ItemID ASC so I've extended it for the other two fields which only added a few extra bytes. It is twice as fast now so if you want to add your solution as an Answer, I'll vote for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try Windowed Aggregates instead of Scalar Subqueries/Outer Apply:

```
SELECT
    i.ID AS ItemID,
    i.ResourceID,
    i.DateAdded,
    i.LocationID,
    i.OwnerID,
    i.Barcode,
    i.MissingReasonID,
    i.DateRemoved,
    ll.PatronID,
    ll.ID AS LoanID,
    ll.IssueDateTime,
    ll.DueDate,
    ll.ReturnDateTime,
    ll.LoanTypeID,
    ll.RenewalCount,
    ll.DeleteSummary,
    ll.ReturnStatusID,
    ll.FineID,
    coalesce(ll.LoanCount, 0)
    COUNT(case when Item.DateRemoved IS NULL then 1 end) 
    over (partition by ResourceID) AS AvailableItemCount
FROM Item i
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        l.ID,
        l.ItemID,
        l.PatronID,
        l.IssueDateTime,
        l.DueDate,
        l.ReturnDateTime,
        l.LoanTypeID,
        l.RenewalCount,
        l.DeleteSummary,
        l.ReturnStatusID,
        l.FineID,
        COUNT(*) over (partition by ItemId) AS LoanCount,
        row_number()
        over (partition by ItemId
              order by  l.IssueDateTime DESC, l.ID DESC) as rn
    FROM Loan l
) as ll
on ll.ItemID = i.ID
and ll.rn = 1
```

Comment: Yes! Take those inline statments and throw them in the garbage.

Comment: Wow, that Answer was quick!
Needed a couple of commas and the LoanCount should return 0 rather than null but I'm sure I can work that out.

Comment: Its hard to tell if it is faster since I only have 18K rows and the original query was nearly instant anyway. BUT your query shows a yellow warning triangle on the Execution Plan and I don't know why.

Comment: The warning is a MemoryGrantWarning - query wanted 617504 but only used 4256.

Comment: @dnoeth..could you pls give a try at stackoverflow.com/questions/53752311/ in sql